# How to protect a public image upload folder from manipulation/direct access

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, file-upload

I've found several answers to this question, but each case was different from mine. Before I spend hours implementing what I think will work, I'd like to get an opinion or two. Who knows, there may be an easier solution that will benefit someone else too!

I'm in the process of creating a website which provides a photo modification service. Each of my customers will be uploading their photos using a modified version of a jQuery/PHP upload script I found on Github ([BlueImp's File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) script- props BlueImp!)  When each image is done uploading, a thumbnail of the image is displayed next to the image's filename.

The upload page creates a folder based on their Order #, and a thumbnail subfolder where the images are stored. For example, for Order # 12345:

/uploads/12345  <-  Folder where the uploaded images will go

/uploads/12345/thumbs <-  Folder where thumbnails will be served from

It's important that clients don't access other clients' photos. I moved the uploads folder outside of my website root, but then the thumbnails weren't displaying when the images finished uploading because, well, they weren't in the website root so the links weren't working.

Here's a solution I thought of:

Separate the folders. Move the main upload folder outside of the document root, but leave the thumbnail folder inside the doc root, so the thumbnails can be served up when each upload completes. When the user has finished uploading their images, delete the thumbnail folder corresponding to that Order #.

Is there a better way to do it? My concern is preventing access to photos (A client will only have to upload them once, then wait for us to finish the modifications. They will NOT have to log back in to download them.)  I don't want someone to be able to access the upload folder via the address bar or anywhere else.  Can I use an .htaccess file to restrict access, but still allow for linking to the thumbnail images via the upload script?

I apologize for the wordy question.  I tried to be as succinct as my limited knowledge of programming would allow.  Thank you in advance for your time and effort in helping with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show the thumbs to each owner customers but not to others?
knowing the Order number (is sequenziell) you can easily try some links and see some photos.

I suggest to use a .htaccess to password the upload folder and to generate a hash number for every thumb that you have to attribute to the order number.

A second solution: password with a .htaccess the upload folder and generate a thumb when you generate the order confirmation page without saving the thumb. (he has to see it only once as you mention).

have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply Nicolas! I really appreciate it! Unfortunately, they may have to log back in to finish uploading their photos if they can't do it all in one sitting. If they do have to log back in, they will need to see the thumbnails of their previously uploaded images.

Comment: I do however very much like the idea of hashing the folder name.  I mentioned above, what about instead of using the Order # for the folder name, I just use a folder name of sha1(SALT.$OrderNumber)?  If anyone with malicious intent cannot guess the folder name, I should be good, right?  Thanks again!!

Comment: you have to hash the filename of the thumb...quiet more easy! but you have to insert that into a database to have a relation between order number and thumb names.

Answer (score 4):

two way around

1. Write a blank `index.html` on each directory, which will prohibit to access files.
2. Write below in *.htaccess* ( if not exist then create this file )

   ```
   Options -Indexes
   ```

   OR  If you want **NO ENTRY outside of the LAN**

   ```
   # no nasty crackers in here!
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
   allow from 192.168.0.0/24
   # this would do the same thing..
   #allow from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.24
   ```

[Reference](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/03/htaccess-directory-listing-enable-disable-allow-deny-prevent-htaccess-directory-listing.html)
[One more](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php)

Comment: Thanks man, this is great! Do you know how to convert this on web.config

Answer (score 0):

Two things that you should do are:

Disable directory indexing.

Always keep the file names random. Map them using the database. i.e file1.jpg->file_af324234324324ff . You can also store the thumbnail file information in the same table.

Comment: Beautiful, I don't know why I didn't think of doing this before. How about instead of using the Order # for the folder name, I just use a folder name of sha1(SALT.$OrderNumber) ?  If nobody knows the folder name (besides the person who uploaded the files), I don't have anything to worry about...  do I?

Comment: You could do that but then if someone discovers the salt you used they have access to all your files not just a single one as in the case it was a random name one that was mapped from the DB.